# Reading doubles from .txt into an array, and playing them in StdAudio

Tags: java, arrays

What I want to do is have my program take double values from a text file, store them in an array, and then have it play the doubles as sound frequencies, for 0.25 seconds for each double.  I have created my array, what I need now is to figure out what code will allow my program to read my doubles.txt, store them in the array I created, and then play them using the `StdAudio`. I'm confused on how to proceed from here.

```
package audioPlay;

import stdlib.StdAudio;
import stdlib.StdIn;

public class PlaySong {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    double[] doubleArray; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: `BufferedInputStream` and `FileInputStream` will be a good start here... Check this tutorial: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion of code reads a file  using Scanner class with a delimiter you specify and store double values into your array.

```
File file = new File("data.txt");
private static final DELIMITER = "YOUR DELIMITER";
double[] doubleArray; 

try {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int i=0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] temp = scanner.nextLine().split(DELIMITER);
            for(int j=0; i<temp.length;++j){
                doubleArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(temp[j]);
                i++;
            }       
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Next, you should learn how StdAudio works.